# Double code is getting change to \" in Spring Rest response

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am having spring rest service where I am sending clob data(rich text field).i.e html data as string.
I can see service is returning fine(debug mode) but when it's coming to browser all double quotes" are getting converted with "\
That's why image rendering is not happening in rich text field.
Please help me to resolve this.

Rest Call:
Actual code I am unable to post due to access issue
`@GetMapping(value="/getRTFData", produces ="application/json") public RTFData get() { }`
RTFData class having field
String contentText;

Actual Service returning :
contentText = "<some src ="https://sample/viewImage/123"
but in response in swagger/postman  i can see coming as
contentText ="<some src=\"https://sample/viewImage/123\">"

Which is extra \ whenever "(double quote).

Please help

Comment: Extra \ is to escape the " characters to maintain the Json Structure else the JSON itself would become invalid. The client that would be consuming the response will get the expected value once it parses the json. InFact you can try converting the same object into json in the code using any Json conversion framework and printing the json. You'll get the same output.

Comment: @KaushikPatel: this data ui is taking to show in ck editor.is there any way to convert there in ui function?